# Is it possible to change the locals dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dispatch

Basically instead of this:

```
context1.a
context1.b()
context2.a
context2.b()
```

I want to write:

```
with context1():
    a
    b()

with context2():
    a
    b()
```

Ideally I would do this by switching out the "locals dictionary" with an object with a custom `__get__`, but I'm not aware of how to do that or if it's even possible.

Why?: I've implemented a kind of predicate dispatching (for fun), but I can only use by explicitly naming the context each time: `context.a() + context.b()` is annoying to write all the time.

Comment: I definitely think you're trying to solve a problem in the hardest way possible. Why can't you just just create a function that invokes these as necessary?

Comment: Is this supposed to be like Javascript's `with`? That's not even a good idea in Javascript; it's deprecated, and prohibited in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Just because a Turing machine can do something doesn't mean that's a good way to communicate your intent to folks.

Simply stick to standard syntax, and then your code will be clear to other engineers.

```
    with context1() as c:
        c.a
        c.b()
```